# error in Livewire 3 with livewire/update status code 302

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, livewire-3

Hi everyone (English is not my first language, so sorry in advance).

I trying to make a multi-language website with laravel 10 and livewire 3. I have a view with authentication and another view for guest. When I use wire:model.live in a search field, in my authentication view works perfect, I get what I searching. But when I search in the guest view, this doesn´t works, laravel redirects to my login and when I see the networks in chrome it shows "livewire/update status code 302".

Even I found here some discutions with a similar issue but I don't find the solution, cause they used livewire 2.

I don't know why is occuring this error, because one view (the guest) has guest middleware and the other has auth middleware.

**this is my web.php code:**

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'guest']
], function() {

Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::post('/livewire/update', $handle);
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.lots'), [GuestLotController::class, 'index'])->name('guest.lots.index');
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.lots-show'), [GuestLotController::class, 'show'])->name('guest.lots.show');

Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
            ->name('login');

Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);
});
```

I appreciate your help. Greetings!!!

That the guest view doesn't redirect to login and make the searching to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue adding this piece of code in RouteServiceProvider.php in the boot function:

```
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::post('/livewire/update', $handle)
        ->middleware('web')
        ->prefix(LaravelLocalization::setLocale());
});
```

This works perfect in both scenarios (Guest and auth).